# how to solve the problem of cannot determine linker language for target?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi:)

when i build the program, found the error like 'cannot determine linker language for link target

below is the my cmakelist.txt's content

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  OpenCV
)

catkin_python_setup()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(opencv_test2 script/opencv_test2.py)

target_link_libraries(opencv_test2
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
 )

 install(PROGRAMS
   script/opencv_test2.py
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
```

please, how to solve this problem?

please know where is the problem exactly.

---

Edit:

i revised my cmakelist.txt

but occur the error that ' cannot speify link libraries for target " scripts/opencv_test1.py" which is not built by this project.

note opencv_test1.py can execute

what is the problem?

i must solve this problem. pleas help me

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(opencv_test1)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES opencv_test1
  CATKIN_DEPENDS opencv2 rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 target_link_libraries(scripts/opencv_test1.py
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208877/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-cannot-determine-linker-language-for-target?/) by [anthuny shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22384/anthuny-shin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-10**:
Don't use answers to update your question, this is not a forum. Update your original question in the future.

I've moved the contents of your answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this your entire `CMakeLists.txt`? Please provide a complete copy.

If this is the complete contents, you seem to be missing two important statements. A typical `CMakeLists.txt` starts with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(your_package)
```

See also [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt - Overall Structure and Ordering](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Overall_Structure_and_Ordering) and [catkin 0.6.14 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Catkin configuration overview - CMakeLists.txt](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/catkin_overview.html#cmakelists-txt)

Also:

> ```
> add_executable(opencv_test2 script/opencv_test2.py)
> ```

You can (and should) use a `CMakeLists.txt` for ROS Python nodes, but you don't use `add_executable(..)` then. See [catkin 0.6.14 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Installing Python scripts and modules](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html) for more info on using `catkin` with Python.

Note that you don't need to install your script / node in order to be able to `rosrun` or `roslaunch` it. You only need a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` to build your package, `catkin` will do the rest.

---

Edit:

> i revised my cmakelist.txt

> but occur the error that ' cannot speify link libraries for target " scripts/opencv_test1.py" which is not built by this project.

Have you read the documentation I linked? You **cannot link Python nodes to anything** using `target_link_libraries(..)`. That is for C/C++/other compiled languages only. There is nothing to link with Python.

Also: `include_directories(..)` is useless with Python nodes. The `PYTHONPATH` is setup by sourcing the correct `setup.(bash|sh|zsh)` after building your workspace.

A minimal `CMakeLists.txt` for a Python only package is probably something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(your_project_name)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

# depending on whether you have any libraries to install/export
#catkin_python_setup()

# add relevant arguments here (CATKIN_DEPENDS etc)
catkin_package()
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dharmendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/53048/dharmendra/) on 2020-05-11**:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(kr120_final)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

catkin_package()

install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN "setup_assistant.launch" EXCLUDE)
install(DIRECTORY config DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})

add_executable(move_group_interface src/move_group_interface.cpp)
target_link_libraries(src/move_group_interface.cpp ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

This is what i have in CMakeList.txt file when i build catkin environment by "catkin_make" command, it does give the same error,

1. i have written node in c++ language,and followed the moveit official documentation.